# Identifying index of matching strings in lists of different sizes

Tags: python, string-matching

I have lists of keywords and lists of data that I want to compare. I would like the return to be a float64 of 1 when any of the strings match.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data=[['history', 'brain', 'scale', 'imaging', 'patterned', 'optogenetics', 'cellular', 'resolution'], ['infectious', 'fun', 'energy', 'iron', 'oxide', 'nanoparticles'], ['billie', 'holiday', 'project', 'bridging', 'art', 'local', 'history', 'community', 'wellness']]
keywords=[['history', 'literature', 'arts', 'humanities', 'philosophy', 'nan'], ['energy', 'optimization', 'systems', 'healthcare', 'policy', 'public', 'health']]
match=np.zeros(shape=(len(data),len(keywords)))
match=pd.DataFrame(match)

data=pd.DataFrame(data)
keywords=pd.DataFrame(keywords)
compare=data.isin(keywords)
```

Currently it only finds the first example of "history" but there is a second and it does not find the term "energy". I would like the output to be:

```
print(match)
     0    1
0  1.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0
2  1.0  0.0
```

I tried a few different itertools methods and enumerate loops without luck, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just required a bunch of loops, better ideas appreciated!

```
for z in range(len(data)):
    for x in data[z]:
        for q in range(len(keywords)):
            for s in keywords[q]:
                if x==s:
                    match.iloc[z,q]+=1
```